# Whitespace converted to rectangle

Tags: c#

When I copy the first paragraph of this page from my browser to a notepad which is under (محمد بصل), I see whitespaces replaced with rectangles in my notepad:
http://www.shorouknews.com/news/view.aspx?cdate=03092012&id=73df0e96-a9d8-44a1-83a8-77b0daf314a7 
How can I convert this in C# code to be inserted properly as whitespace in a SQL Server table?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely that the characters used in the source web page are not supported by the font used by notepad. As long as the character codes are maintained by everything (your IDE, DB library and so on), you should be fine. Of course, this is an assumption. I have not tried out Visual Studio's extended character support myself.